# How to associate External Data Source with a named credentials?

Tags: dataextensions, data, namedcredentials, auth-provider

I created an External Data Source following the steps given in the following link :
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.search_define_federated_search.htm&type=5

However the External Data Source that I am using doesn't support Open ID connect or OAuth.

Is it possible for me to setup a external data source with auth provider that uses basic auth or jwt auth?